# How to change the text view message everyday automatically?

Tags: java, android, button, textview

In my app, I have a fragment with a button and a TextView.
I want to show a dynamic message in a TextView that should change everyday.

when I first click on the button, the TextView should show "Day 1" and after each day(at 12 AM) the TextView automatically should change to "day 2", "day 3" until "day 10" that lasts for 10 days, and if I click on the button again, TextView shows the message "THE END".

what should I do for that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i assume you know how to set and show a TextView.

1) You need to store the date when you first click on the button (to close your app and keep your data safe).
You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for that, and store the day of week, for exemple:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // Or other Calendar value

SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putInt(DAY_START, day);
editor.commit(); // commit is important here.
```

2) On your activity **onCreate** methods, get the day start in preference.

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
int dayStart = (shared.getInt(DAY_START, 1));
```

3) To know which day we are, just substract value

```
int today = day - dayStart; // Add +1 if u want to say "day 1" for 0 value
```

4) Use **Calendar** Class again to get the hour of the day.

5) Just add a condition for showing your END message.

```
If (today == 10) {
    // message
}
```

It's not a complete code but you can see the logic.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check current date and time using `Calendar` class. Then use that info to display appropriate text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to android. could you please explain more?

Comment: `Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()` This gives you object with current date and time. To get info from `Calendar` object use `Calendar.get()` i.e. `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`. See here for more constants [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY). If you have current date and time then you're able to say if we already have a new day or not. If yes then increment the number of day you are displaying on the button. You can store this number in `SharedPreferences` so that it won't be lost between next starts of your app.

Comment: You should also store date of last number of day change in `SharedPreferences` to be able to compare that date and current time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in your onStart method:

```
String whatDayisIt = "Day 1";

Button b = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_NAME)
b.setText(whatDayisIt)
```

I'm assuming you're asking more about the button logic and figuring out what day it actually is.

Comment: I know this, but how it changes to day 2, when the system date changes?

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it
Note: You might need to store the current `count` value so when the app is killed, the previous value of `count` will be picked up, the easiest way to implement this is by using `SharedPreferences`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // retrieve an instance of the calendar to query Time-related info

SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //retrieve an instance of the SharedPreferences to store primitive data value.
SharedPreferences.Editor edtior = pref.edit();//every change to the preferences must pass through an SharedPreferences.Editor, so call pref.edit() to retrive one;

int count = 1; //to keep track of the current day
while (count <= 10)
{

    if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) ==  12 && calendar.get(Calender.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM) // if it is at 12 AM in the morning
    {
        count = pref.getInt("count", 1);//retrieve the count value if it is saved previously with an identifier of count, otherwise, return 1 as a default value.
        textView.setText("Day " + count);
        count++;//indicate that new day has come

        if(this.isFinishing())//check if the user is leaving the app by pressing the back key, if true, we need to store the current count value which is the current day
        {
             editor.putInt("count", count);
             editor.commit(); //need to commit the change to persist it
        }

    }
}

text.setText("The End");
```